# Tkinter - How do you centre text on a LabelFrame?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-layout

I want to centre the text on a LabelFrame. I have tried using `side="centre"` and `anchor="centre"` but I just get an `unknown option '-anchor'`.

I tried searching online but nothing is coming up for a LabelFrame.
Is there anything else I could try?

The image below is an example of what I am trying to change:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THkUE.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `labelanchor="n"` option.